# Meaning of "sharp"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

Context ([New York Times](http://travel.nytimes.com/2010/06/20/travel/20hotels.html)):

> Still, rooms were large by the city’s pint-size standards, service was **sharp**, and for the moment, they offer some of the best values around.

Does *sharp* here mean definition 20 (shrewd to the point of dishonesty) in [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sharp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it means *punctual* in this case.

Comment: cf "Quick sharp! Look alive!", as my grandmother used to say.

Answer (score 1):

**Oxford English Dictionary**:

**7**. As a general term of approbation. orig. U.S. slang.
  a. Excellent, fine.

Comment: I'm sure it's @JeffSahol's sense that's intended here.